# I approved an edit too quickly - can I revert this?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I approved the first edit to [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/22983/work-pressure-due-to-ineffecient-co-worker) (the one made by user [yochannah](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/12655/yochannah)), but regret doing so.

**Can I revert this somehow?** I could not find a way. I have 2031 rep at the moment.

[FWIW: Reason: She italicized a sentence that may have only been an interpretation by the OP - it does not deserve the emphasis.]

Comment: 'She', not 'he' ;)

Comment: Sorry, did not look at your profile ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to revert your approval of a suggested edit. However, once a suggested edit gets approved (or rejected) you can always edit again to fix remaining problems.

In this case, I went ahead and edited to remove the italics and also fix remaining problems, like the title, other grammatical issues, and punctuation issues. I marked the suggested edit as helpful due to the fixes in other areas, but rejecting may arguably also have been a correct approach considering there were other areas left untended.

Ideally, suggested edits should fix *all* problems with a post, unless the edit fixes a major problem with the post, such as a title edit or clarifying something in the body of importance. Hope this helps.

Comment: "you can always edit again" Thanks. Why did I not think of that ;-) ?